# Validation of relation models in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, relationship

How can I validate relations in models in RoR? For example I have 3 models:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog
  has_one :user, :through => :blog

  validates :blog_id, :presence => true
end

class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blogs
  has_many :posts, :through => :blogs
end
```

And in my controller:

```
@post = current_user.blogs.find(params[:post].delete(:blog_id)).posts.build(params[:post])
```

But when I want to create post I get:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: blog_id
```

I shouldn't get this error, because I am delete blog_id from params hash, or don't? Any way, what the better way of validating blog_id accessory to User.blogs in my Post model?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the on which blog the post should be published after writing, you have to put the blog_id into the whitelist by setting `attr_accessible`

So in your example your Post model should look like

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog

  attr_accessible :blog_id, :title, :content
  validates :blog_id, :presence => true
end​
```

Besides this. Be careful how you set up your relation. The difference between `has_one` and `belongs_to` is where the foreign key goes. It goes to where you define the `belongs_to`. `has_one` says that one of something is yours, so something points back to you. It doesn't make much sense to say that a Post `has_one` user...

It is enough to have a Post only belong to a Blog. You still can do something like `current_user.posts` by how you setup the relationship in the user model like you already did...

I'd recommend reading  the following links http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Thx, but i askrd about something other. For example, user #1 has #1 and #2 blogs, and user #2 has #3 and #4 blogs. How can i validate blog_id in Post model, that for user 1 it can be only #1 or #2 and #3 or #4 for user #2? And why i get error if i'm using params[:post].delete(:blog_id)?

Answer (score 0):

Validations for :blog_id in Post model is perfect.

```
@post = current_user.blogs.find(params[:post].delete(:blog_id)).posts.build(params[:post])
```

:blog_id is deleted from params[:post], but let's look at the thing from a different view.

```
@blog = current_user.blogs.find(params[:post].delete(:blog_id))
@post = @blog.build(params[:post])
```

params[:post] does not have :blog_id, but build method automatically assigns blog_id to @blog.id.
  That's why error for :blog_id is not coming up.

If you wanna avoid the mass assignment warning, you can make the :blog_id attribute accessible.